# Is there a way to use SQLite commands in the C++ interface for SQLite?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to import a CSV file into a SQLite Database through C++ code. Normally through the SQLite command line I would go

> sqlite3 db

> .import statistics.csv stats

I am wondering how to do this exact same thing through the C++ Interface for SQLite.

Comment: The source for SQLite is public domain. You can download it and read it to see what the `.import` command does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public SQLite C++ API to do what `import` does exactly.  You need to read the CSV file yourself and insert the values as normal.